# Cardview com várias imagens

Tags: android

Alguém poderia me ajudar como faço para cada card desse ai trocar as imagens utilizando a biblioteca picasso ?

[image: Carviews com várias imagens]

Comment: Já viu a [documentação oficial](http://square.github.io/picasso/)? No primeiro parágrafo há um exemplo em uma linha de como baixar uma imagem e colocar num ImageView.

Comment: se você fez essa lista e esta exibindo essa imagens oque você apenas tem que fazer é ter as imagens em um arry list e rodar elas no .load do picasso percorrendo a lista... se quiser edite sua pergunta coloque a parte do código que você fez essa lista, e eu posto mais tarde uma resposta.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Sim cara isso é fácil. Quero saber para colocar em um listview.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta no onBindViewHolder que nem no exemplo abaixo, vai funcionar.
Mas acredito que há alternativas com performance melhores.

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //holder.mTextViewTitle.setText(mMovies.getJSONObject(position).get("id").toString());
        holder.mTextViewTitle.setText(mMovies.get(position).getmTitle());

        holder.idItem = mMovies.get(position).getmId();


        Picasso.with(holder.context).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" +
            mMovies.get(position).getmPosterPath())
            .into(holder.mMovieImageView);

}
```

Comment: Oi Alan, não entendi. Você pode me explicar melhor ?